# Removing element from Array-list not working, duplicates happening?(basic bingo game)

Tags: java

I tired to make a super basic bingo go(no need to over complicate stuff)

```
package bingo;

 import java.util.*;

public class Bingo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rn = new Random();
    ArrayList bingo = new ArrayList();
    final int MAX = 50;
    int no  = rn.nextInt(49);
    boolean finished = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        bingo.add(i);
    }


    while(!finished){
       // Keep the number it can generate the same size as the array-list
        no  = rn.nextInt(bingo.size());
```

is this where it goes wrong? instead of removing the number e.g "10", does it remove the element in position 10 in the array?

```
  if(bingo.contains(no)){
            System.out.println(no);
            bingo.remove(no);
        }

        if(bingo.isEmpty()){
            finished = true;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is your exact requirement from the code inside the while loop? Is it to remove elements in bingo arraylist from last to first?

Comment: You're saying you don't want to overcomplicate things but the problem you're having would probably have been prevented by specifying the type of ArrayList (judging from almas shaikh's answer)

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek true, I have done arraylists before but forgot how to implement them, I did a quick google and it came up with that way of doing array lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two overloaded version of remove method in arrayList.

Difference between two overloaded api of [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) method is [One](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) that accepts Object and [other](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) which accepts primitive index parameter. And you are specifying primitive value i.e. 10.

If you want to remove element with content as 10, you change the following line from:

```
int no  = ...
```

To

```
Integer no  = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`bingo.remove(no)` calls `remove(int index)`, which removes the element whose index is `no`, not the element whose value is `no`. If you want to remove the element whose value is no, you need to use `remove(Object o)`, which expects a reference type. For example, `bingo.remove(Integer.valueOf(no));`.

Comment: im assuming thats why I'm getting duplicates.

Comment: while trying to post an answer like this I've seen your answer posted, I cancelled my answer. I support this. ויוה ישראל +1